# Why is this CAML Query returning all items regardless of the <Where> element definition?

Tags: 2010, javascript, caml-query

I'm trying to retrieve a list of items where a specific field matches a specific value.  There is likely going to be multiple items returned when the query is successful.

Here's what my CAML query looks like:

```
//init the query object             
itemQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

//build the query string
//Equiv to SELECT * FROM list WHERE CollectiveNum = strCollectiveNum (parameter)
itemQueryString = '<Where>';
itemQueryString +='<Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Collective #\'/><Value Type=\'Lookup\'>' + strCollectiveNum + '</Value></Eq>';
itemQueryString +='</Where>';

itemQuery.getitems(itemQuery);
```

No matter what this query returns all items! I'm confused.  It's really unclear to me why this would be so.

Next, If I follow the example in the section "Retrieving Items from a List Using Javascript" on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185007%28v=office.14%29.aspx) by adding

```
<View><Query>
```

and

```
</Query></View>
```

around my query string it throws an alert with a message that says "Request failed. One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings to delete these fields. undefined"

Where am I going wrong?  I'd be glad to post any other pieces of my script if needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CAML uses the internal name of the column in question. [Spaces and symbols are "encoded"](http://abstractspaces.wordpress.com/2008/05/07/sharepoint-column-names-internal-name-mappings-for-non-alphabet/).

Space: `_x0020_`

Hash: `_x0023_`

```
<Where>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='Collective_x0020__x0023_' LookupId='TRUE' />
        <Value Type='Lookup'>1</Value>
    </Eq>
</Where>
```

Comment: This, although I tend to take things a step further and interrogate the list via Powershell to determine what the internalname of the field is. You never know when a user might have originally created a field under the name you're using, then deleted it, then re-added it, for instance.

Comment: Actually, the site was made by myself - an amateur, who only learned about the naming/renaming issue after the site went into use :( It's not realistic for me to recreate the content with proper names.  Thanks for this help.  It seems like a weird convention to return all items when a query isn't proper..  The end result in my test server is that all items were deleted when I expected just particular items tagged with that value to be deleted.  Changing the field name worked just fine and I'm seeing the results I've expected.  Thanks!

Comment: We were all amateurs. When I create a list via the GUI I like to first set my field names as a single string with no special characters. That sets the `Internal Name`, then I go back and change the field title so that it looks ok in the GUI.

Comment: Another way to find the internal name of a field is in IE go to the list/library settings page, under columns right click the field and select 'properties'. At the end of the Address (URL) you will see `Field=InternalName` where InternalName is the internal name of the field you are looking at.

Answer (score 3):

When all items return it is almost always caused by an invalid CAML query. For the CAML attribute 'FieldRef' you need to use the internal name which cannot contain a whitespace.

Replace

```
 FieldRef Name="Collective #"
```

With

```
 FieldRef Name="Collective_x0020_#"
```

If still incorrect use powershell to find the field name.

---

Personally I would do (C#)

```
 SPQuery myQuery = new SPQuery();
 myQuery.Query ="<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Collective_x0020_#'/><Value Type='Lookup'>"+yourValue"+</Value></Eq></Where>";
 MyCollection = MyList.GetItems(myQuery);
```

Comment: It seems the "#" character isn't accepted as valid.  You just replace it with "<underscore>0023<underscore>" as suggested below.  I don't have access to PowerShell but I can view the raw HTML of any page using this list and find that the internal name is indeed "Collective_0020__0023_".